# Class, Inner Class, Package, Interface, Abstract Class

Tags: dart

In java we have Class, Inner Class, Package, Abstract Class. What is the equivalent  class/structure and how to define the same in DART

```
1. Class
2. Inner Class
3. Package
4. Abstract Class
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `class`
2. not supported
3. in Dart a project is named package
4. `abstract class`